# Is it possible to mount a DVD iso to look like it's a DVD drive?

Tags: mount, optical-drive, dvd, iso

I have an old game DVD (Chessmaster 9000) that I bought legit (I swear), and I would like to play it on my Mac Air, which has no optical drive. With another game (Civ V) I've had success data-dumping the DVD to an iso in linux, and then mounting the iso on the Mac Air. But Chessmaster 9000 is the kind of game that needs the disc *in* the drive to play. Having the iso mounted is not enough.

Is there a way to convince the Mac Air that it has a disk in a drive? My best hunch so far is that if it *is* possible, it involves a `vndevice` command, but I have had no luck so far, and documentation for it is very thin on the ground. I'm looking for the magic to make this work via a low-level command-line, rather than the commercial (but cheap) software that is available in one answer.

- It looks like it requires writing your own low-level driver for the fake device. In other words, worth $10 to me! Accepting @Guido's answer.

Comment: If it is very old, it will be a PowerPC program which will not run on modern OS X versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with `DAEMON Tools Lite for Mac`, you can download here:

http://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtMacLite

This software has figured out how to trick the computer to thinking a DVD is mounted and I don't know if you can re-implement it via the command line tool `vndevice` you mentioned.

Comment: How does this tool differ from mounting .iso images directly via Finder?

Comment: I used it to mount images that were unsupported by Finder, and maybe they use a different engine (or they simulate a dvd drive) to mount the file. I wrote `try` not `sure will work`

Comment: I had trouble working out the weird interface at first, but it turns out *this works*! Thanks @GuidoPreite. Now: what's the low-level magic going on here? I can't help think there's some simple CLI trick that doesn't require $10 activation ... but if not, that's a worthwhile $10 in my view.

Comment: For the benefit of others who might try the light version: click the "change" button on the first splash screen to activate your trial period. (?!) Then a new "Remote" device shows up. The only way I found to mount anything on it, though, was to change the preferences of Daemon Tools to make a key combination for mounting a new image. (?!) From there, hit the key combo you chose, and you will be able to pick your iso.

Comment: Glad you solved, I really don't know how they implemented

Comment: The **DAEMON Tools** suggested above I have purchased and installed in order to use virtual devices for purchased legitimate DVDs with an program that wanted to run another laptop without a CD/DVD (most of them don't have it now).
It didn't work and was still getting "Insert CD/DVD into drive" message when launching it same as when mounted using Disk Utility so **the selected answer is NOT CORRECT and misleading - it DOES NOT trick software to think it's a physical drive**.

Comment: Also, many people complain about third-party software being installed without user consent when using Deamon Tools Free version so BEWARE. The paid version is badly developed anyway i.e. it's not running as a proper app with an icon in the bottom bar (Mac) that can be closed nor it's listed in processes so it's quite hidden and virtually impossible to close for standard users who don't know shell. I will be reinstalling my laptop anyway because don't trust these guys - they're teaming up with aggresive malware companies hence suspect and found traces of their software even after uninstallation

Comment: why did you buy? the software has a trial, if it didn't work for you doesn't mean that was not working for the user asked the question. If your legitimate DVD implements a copy protection system (for example) means that they developed a copy protection system capable to detect if is a virtual drive